# Proof for a simplicial morphism

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Sorry for the title but I can't come up with another one...

...

Suppose X and Y are simplicial sets
and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a map
such that:

1.) f maps dimensions the right way,
    that is for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}^0$
    we have $f_n := f : X_n \rightarrow Y_n$

2.) f commutes with all face maps in all
    dimensions, that is $f_{n-1} \circ d^n_k = d^n_k \circ f_n$
    for all $n,k \in \mathbb{N}^0$ with $k \leq n$

3.) $f$ commutes with the degeneracy $s_n$
    that is $f_{n+1}s_n=s_nf_n$ in any dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}^0$

```
(EDIT: So up to this point we only know about commutation with ONE degeneracy)
```

Is $f$ a simplicial morphism?

( In my particular situation X and Y are 
Kan in addition and moreover X is 2-coskeletal
and Y is n-coskeletal for n>=2 )

If this only holds under additional assumptions, feel free to write just
about that particular situation.

Comment: If I'm not missing something, 1) - 3) just say that f is a simplicial map (see Definition 1.2 in May's book on simplicial objects in algebraic topology - online: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS1965.html - or VIII.5 in MacLane's book on homology). What's the definition of a simplicial morphism ? 

Comment: A simplicial morphism is a simplicial map, so it is.

Comment: Mirco's condition (3) only mentions the *last* degeneracy s_n.  So it's not obviously a simplicial map/morphism.  